# Use text view of current app instead of Custom text View

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to use this library for my emojicons https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon.
I have implemented it with my soft keyboard but it's not doing anything as in the code (MainActivity) of the given link, it uses EmojiconEditText instead of normal text view of any android app. Is there any way so that I can use edit text of any app instead of this custom one. My current source code for emoji is this.

```
popup = new EmojiconsPopup(mInputView, this);
popup.setOnEmojiconClickedListener(new EmojiconGridView.OnEmojiconClickedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEmojiconClicked(Emojicon emojicon) {
            if (emojicon == null){
                return;
            }
            emojicon.getEmoji();
        }
    });
```

In this, I cannot figure out how to fetch Unicode for that particular emoji. If someone can help me how do I fetch emoji Unicode?
The code for emoji Unicode is in this https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/tree/master/lib/src/github/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/emoji

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer after some struggle. I just need to call that string of unicodes in it with current input connection.

```
String text = emojicon.getEmoji();
mComposing.append(text);
commitTyped(getCurrentInputConnection());
```